# Idea behind Reverse Insertion Check

Tags: programming, programmer

I read through universal device programmer (device that program ICs like AVRs, PICs, EEPROM, etc) like items in links below, I found that these programmers perform these checks:

- insertion test.
- reverse insertion check.
- contact check.

can you help me telling how these checks can be done without damaging the Chip?

[sample 1](https://www.elnec.com/en/products/device-programmers/beeprog/)

[sample 2](http://www.advin.com/chip-programmer.htm)

Answer (score 0):

They protect the chip by carefully limiting the amount of current that can flow during the initial attempts to power up the chip. Most input protection diodes can safely handle at least 10 mA.

Comment: do you mean by measuring the current drawn during power up? i think in reverse insertion the device will sink too much current and blow up, what is the location of the input protection diodes? is it inside the chip or the device programmer?